# First showon works as expected, all others don't

Tags: component, joomla-4.x, form-fields-types, showon

I have various such pairs in a form:

```
<field
        name="hasEndDate"
        type="list"
        label="Hat Enddatum?"
        default="1"
>
    <option value="0">Nein</option>
    <option value="1">Ja</option>
</field>

<field
        name="endDate"
        type="calendar"
        translateformat="true"
        singleheader="false"
        showtime="true"
        timeformat="24"
        todaybutton="true"
        label="Ende: Datum und Zeit"
        weeknumbers="true"
        size="20"
        filter="server_utc"
        showon="hasEndDate:1"
/>
```

While the first `showon` in the first tab of the edit form makes the field appear / disappear, **all other suchlike marked fields, never disappear**.

I tried different types of the source field - no change at all.

> - Any ideas why?
> - Is the `showon` operation only guaranteed on the first tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `showon` feature of XML fields's settings in Joomla works well in Joomla 4 according to my tests. The issue that 'showon' works or not does not have too much to do with HTML **Tabs** basically, but it has a lot to do with XML **Fields** and **Field**. You create HTML Tabs and display different Fieldsets/Fields/Field within the different Tabs and the fields within the tabs are usually within different **Fields** nodes in the XML.

For example you have **X number of Tabs** and you set a showon condition for a field in your **5th Fieldsets/Fields** (in 5th Tab of your Form) dependent on a **Field** value in **4th Fieldsets' Fields'** (in 4th Tab), then you should target the `<Field>` of the targeted particular `<Fields>` node when you are setting a `showon` condition, like `"fieldsname.fieldname:1"`, so you not only set `fieldname:1`.

That way in your 5th Tab the field with a showon condition - targeting the 4th Tab's field value - will respond according to the 4th Tabs field value setting.

In my test XML you can see this setting in the different `<Fieldsets>` and `<Fields>`. For you the last `<Field>` is interesting to check in this example.

```
<fieldset name = "showg">
    <fields name="showfieldsg">
       <field
                name="hasEndDate"
                type="list"
                label="Hat Enddatum?"
                default="1"
        >
            <option value="0">Nein</option>
            <option value="1">Ja</option>
        </field>

        <field
                name="endDate"
                type="calendar"
                translateformat="true"
                singleheader="false"
                showtime="true"
                timeformat="24"
                todaybutton="true"
                label="Ende: Datum und Zeit"
                weeknumbers="true"
                size="20"
                filter="server_utc"
                showon="hasEndDate:1"
        />
        <field
                name="nextTabValue"
                type="list"
                label="Next Tab Field show?"
                default="1"
        >
            <option value="0">No</option>
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </field>
    </fields>
</fieldset>
<fieldset name = "showi">
    <fields name="showfieldsi">
        <field
                name="TestPrevTab"
                type="list"
                label="Test Previous Tab Setting"
                default="1"
                showon="showfieldsg.nextTabValue:1"
        >
            <option value="0">No</option>
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
        </field>
    </fields>
</fieldset>
```

So shortly, within the same Fieldsets' Fields the showon condition works as usual but if one of your fields depends on another Fieldset's Fields value then you should target the `Fieldsname.Fieldname` in the showon condition and it will work.

And the visual working result of these tabs and field's showon test in Tabs is here:

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/1135/Himm8V.gif

Comment: Sounds good, Zollie! I'd check that. I think, that I referenced fields within the same tab/fieldset. But let's see. Will come back.

Comment: Quite likely, I assigned two tabs  identical names. Therefore, things didn't work as expected. Thanks again for your assistance!